# Insert sequential number in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I added an empty column to a table and now I want to insert sequential numbers to its rows. Is it possible to do it using SQL?

Comment: Update them with row num, you can find examples in SO

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Run the following queries to have incremented value in `yourField` column:

```
SELECT @i:=0;
UPDATE yourTable SET yourField = @i:=@i+1;
```

Comment: Worth noting that first inserted value is 1, not 0

Comment: For very large tables, you may run out of InnoDB locks. Increase `@@innodb_buffer_pool_size` to accommodate.

Comment: Advice from new MySQL versions like 8: `Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)`.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments you can update every row with its row number,

Here is a [link](http://jimlife.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/) to how to calculate rownum in MySQL.

To rephrase:

```
update player,
       (select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘rank’, p.* 
        from player p,
        (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
        order by score desc) player1
 set thatColumn= rank
 where player.id = player1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [auto increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)
if you wanted to have incremental number in your table for each insert that you do

```
create table WithAutoInc(somID int AUTO_INCREMENT,somName_ char(100) ,primary key(somID ));
```

now to insert you can do this

```
 insert into WithAutoInc (somName_) values ('presley');
```

the result is

[image]