# How to use table aliases with MYSQL UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I have to update a mysql table using PHP's mysql_query() function. Therefore I need to send the following UPDATE query in only one statement:

```
SET @i = 0;

UPDATE mytable SET id=(@i:=@i+1);
```

I have read some examples where this can be done with SELECT statements using table aliases like:

```
SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank, t1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable) t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2
```

Is there some way to use these table aliases with the UPDATE statement that I need to use?

Edit:

Based on Topher Hunt's answer, I think I could create a copy of mytable using:

CREATE TABLE mytable_copy SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS id, t1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable) t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2

Then DROP mytable and RENAME mytable_copy to mytable.

Would this statement create an exact copy of mytable, with the same field types and lenghts that the ones in mytable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just drop this column and add a new column as a primary key with auto_increment?  This will automatically assign the values you require.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN id;

ALTER TABLE mytable ADD ( id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY );

-or- as you requested...

UPDATE mytable
  JOIN (SELECT @xxx := 0) AS v1 
   SET id = (@xxx := @xxx + 1)
;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are right, dropping the column and adding a new one as a primary key with auto_increment is the most straightforward way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

If you use JOINs between your tables, the syntax is very similar between SELECT and UPDATE statements. Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 a
    JOIN table2 b ON a.something = b.something ## (conditions for linking tables)
    JOIN table3 c ON b.something = c.something
WHERE a.something = 'value'
```

A SELECT statement that joins 3 tables, can be turned around into an UPDATE statement just by removing the SELECT line, changing the word FROM to UPDATE, and adding a "SET" clause to say what you want to change. Like this:

```
UPDATE table1 a
    JOIN table2 b ON a.something = b.something ## (conditions for linking tables)
    JOIN table3 c ON b.something = c.something
SET a.variable = 'value2', 
    b.something = 'value3',
    c.somethingelse = 'value4'
WHERE a.something = 'value';
```

You can make changes to lots of fields at the same time, if needed; just separate each SET item with commas.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In this particular case, mytable has no indexes. Therefore it is difficult to use JOIN and WHERE clauses. That is why I wanted to use that UPDATE statement to have a unique index in mytable.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. I'm confused about how your tables are set up such that JOINS wouldn't do the job, and I suspect it's unnecessary to drop and re-create a table just to do an update. To help me understand, could you clarify where the new value (that you are saving in the updated table) is coming from? Are you getting that value from another table, or is it inserted as a "constant" element based on a PHP variable?

Comment: The updated value would just be a consecutive number: 1,2,3,4...I was trying to use a PHP variable (i=i+1) to UPDATE each row of the table. However, since the table has no indexes, there could be more than one row in which: "WHERE a=somevalue AND b=someothervalue" is true. The table has 10 fields. There are no rows with the same values in all the 10 fiels, so I could use WHERE a=somevalue AND b=someothervalue AND c=yetanothervalue ...AND j = finalvalue, but I was trying an easier way to do it

Comment: Ah, so you're trying to add something like a unique sequential ID value after-the-fact? If you do this by injecting PHP code, you'll be limited to running one UPDATE query per row in the database, since any PHP you inject will apply to all rows updated. However you can use Mysql variables to update many rows at once using this technique (much much faster, but test this beforehand to ensure you're comfortable with the technique!) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862215/insert-sequential-number-in-mysql