# Insert sequential numbers based on another field - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a similar question 
[Insert sequential number in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862215/insert-sequential-number-in-mysql)

I want to insert sequential numbers to the table, but based on another field. I have two columns `page_numner` and `parent`, so the rows with same parent should have `page_number` as consequtive numbers. If parent changes, the page should start from 1 again and increase by one.

I was thinking to use smth like this

```
SELECT @i:=0;
SELECT @p:=0;

UPDATE my_table AS t SET page_number = CASE
WHEN @p = t.`parent` THEN @i:=@i+1 
ELSE 1 -- assign current parent to @p ??
END
```

but, it cant figure out how to assign the new parent into `@p` for the `else` case.

Please note, that I am trying to achieve this with pure mysql (if possible of course)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want with this code:

```
set @p := -1;
set @i := 0;

UPDATE my_table t
    SET page_number = (CASE WHEN @p = t.`parent` THEN @i := @i+ 1 
                            WHEN (@p := t.parent) = NULL THEN NULL -- never happens
                            ELSE @i := 1
                       END)
    ORDER BY t.parent;
```

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't allow both `ORDER BY` and `JOIN` in the same `UPDATE` query.  If it did, you could initialize the variables in the query.

Note the second condition just does the assignment.  `= NULL` never returns `TRUE`.

Comment: MySQL absolutely supports `ORDER BY` and `JOIN` in the same query.

Comment: @defines . . . I thought the context was obvious.  That was referring to an `UPDATE`:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this almost worked, but one small issue I am trying to figure out. lets say for `parent=1` it assigned the page numbers from 1 to 15, for the `parent=2` the first page number is 1, but the second is 16, which I guess because the var `@i` ended with 15, is there a way to reset it to 0 again when the parent changes ? thanks

Comment: @dav . . . Oops, I missed that really important assignment.  I just fixed it.

Comment: it worked !, learnt smth new(and important) ))) , thanks a lot