# MySQL update with sequential number yields NULL

Tags: mysql

I want to update the values of a column with the name of a related entry appended with a number for each row. I've seen a couple of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617056/updating-columns-with-a-sequence-number-mysql) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862215/insert-sequential-number-in-mysql) which give roughly the same answer, but when I try the below, I get `NULL` added instead.

```
SET @i = 0;
UPDATE matrix_data md
SET col_id_4 = concat((SELECT title from titles t WHERE t.entry_id = md.entry_id), (@i:=@i+1));
```

If I replace `(@i:=@i+1)` with a static value, then the update works OK.

The `col_id_4` column is set to `text`. Does the above only work with numeric column types? And if so, how do I achieve what I want to do?

Comment: If entry_id is unique in titles, I'd try doing the concatenation in the SELECT...  e.g. `SET col_id_4 = (SELECT CONCAT(t.title,(@i:=@i+1)) FROM t...)`.  For testing, I'd run just the SELECT by itself, with a literal in place of `md.entry_id`, to see if that's returning a NULL or not.

Comment: Gave that a go and the output is still NULL.

Comment: I'd recommend testing just the SELECT by itself. Return `t.title` and `@i` along with the result of the CONCAT expression, e,g. `SELECT @i AS i0, CONCAT(t.title,(@i:=@i+1)), t.title, @i AS i2 FROM titles t WHERE t.entry_id = ?`

Comment: The only one that outputs a value other than `NULL` is `t.title`.

Comment: Are you sure you executed the statement to initialize @i ? You show a statement to do that.  If `SELECT @i` is returning NULL, then it seems like the `SET @i = 0` statement didn't execute.

Comment: Actually I wasn't executing properly, no. I have done now and your original suggestion worked fine so if you'd like to make it an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

How about you take the primary key of the *titles* table instead of using the iterator, thus filling in *col_id_4* with a concatenation of *titles.title* and *titles.entry_id*, thus…

```
UPDATE matrix_data 
INNER JOIN titles ON matrix_data.entry_id = titles.entry_id 
SET matrix_data.col_id_4 = CONCAT(titles.title, "_", titles.entry_id)
```

Or maybe it’s a type issue; casting the iterator to char(50) as we concatenate with the string should work. Tested in a rudimentary database, not #craftcms or #eecms specifically.

```
SET @i := 0;

UPDATE matrix_data 
INNER JOIN titles ON matrix_data.entry_id = titles.entry_id 
SET matrix_data.col_id_4 = CONCAT(titles.title, "_", CAST(@i := @i + 1 as CHAR(50)))
```

Comment: Turns out I didn't need to use `cast`; I just wasn't executing `SET @i = 0` properly to start with.