# Error on inserting sequential number in MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I have to insert sequential number from 1 to N in an empty column in a database. Android Studio is giving me the following error when I run my code:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: ":" (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT @i:=0; UPDATE table_name SET column_one = @i:=@i+1;
```

My line of code:

```
    db.execSQL("SELECT @i:=0; UPDATE table_name SET column_one = @i:=@i+1;");
```

(Please note when I change MySQL statement between parenthesis the code runs and gets executed)

Source of SQL code:

[Insert sequential number in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862215/insert-sequential-number-in-mysql)

I'm new in Java, Android Studio and MySQL.

What am I missing here?

Help me to understand why MySQL @i:=@i+1 expression is not running properly in Android Studio.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because android doesn't have mysql from a box, there is SqLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because android database is using sqlite，but sqlite dose not supported “@”，if you want batch processing ，I  suggest you use Java

Comment: Do you mean to create, save and maintain database purely on Java within Android platform? And any suggestion where to start?

Comment: Try this http://mobilesiri.com/android-sqlite-database-tutorial-using-android-studio/

Comment: Thanks for help, hope I can put website info together and come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
database.execSQL("SELECT " + @i + " :=0   ;  UPDATE table_name SET column_one = " +  @i + " := " + @i "+1;");
```

Comment: Both @i outside of parenthesis are now giving me an error before even running the code